# How to change the value in an array with a function

Tags: c

I have an array, which will stay in a global state.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int linhas = 3;
    int colunas = 3;
    char tabela[linhas][colunas];
    
}
```

Then I would like to be able to fill that table in a function
and have another function that prints it.

The question here is, how can I target the table elements and change them in the fuction?

I tried with pointers but I guess I lack the proper understanding of it to make it work properly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int linhas = 3;
    int colunas = 3;
    char tabela[linhas][colunas];
    
    fillTable(linhas, colunas, tabela);
    
    printTable(linhas, colunas, tabela);
    
}


int fillTable(char *tab, int linhas, int colunas){
    
    for(int x = 0; x < linhas; x++ ){
        for( int y = 0; y < colunas; y++){
            *tab[x][y] = '_';
        }
    }
    
}
int printTable(int linhas, int colunas,char *tab[linhas][colunas]){
    
    
    for(int x = 0; x < linhas; x++ ){
        for( int y = 0; y < colunas; y++){
            printf("%c\t",*tab[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Surely you are getting compiler warnings/errors?

Comment: You will definitely want to forward declare `fillTable` and `printTable` as well as consider why both would have a return type of `int` when neither return any value.

Answer (score 0):

When we are working with arrays then the base variable is itself a pointer. For example in your case if you access only tabela then it is a pointer. So you can modify the code as follows.

```
int fillTable(char *tab, int linhas, int colunas){
    
  for(int x = 0; x < linhas; x++ ){
     for( int y = 0; y < colunas; y++){
         *((tab+x)+y) = '_';
     }
  }
}
```

and the second one can be modified as follows.

```
  int printTable(int linhas, int colunas,char *tab){
        for(int x = 0; x < linhas; x++ ){
            for( int y = 0; y < colunas; y++){
                printf("%c\t",*((tab+x)+y));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
   }
```

Comment: This does not work, you cannot pass a 2 dimensional array to a regular `char*` like that.

Comment: Yes we can pass the 2 dimensional array to regular char* as it is just regular array in memory. However we can't access it in ``var[][]`` representation that was my mistake. Thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 0):

If the array will stay in a global state, I am assuming that its size will never change. In C, you can only pass an array to a function if you know beforehand what the size of the array will be. If this is not the case, you will have to use pointers.

In your case, what you can do is pass your 2 dimensional array as is, with the size defined beforehand.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINHAS 3
#define COLUNAS 3

void fillTable(char tab[LINHAS][COLUNAS]) {
    for(int x = 0; x < LINHAS; x++ ){
        for( int y = 0; y < COLUNAS; y++){
            tab[x][y] = '_';
        }
    }
}

void printTable(char tab[LINHAS][COLUNAS]){
    for(int x = 0; x < LINHAS; x++ ){
        for( int y = 0; y < COLUNAS; y++){
            printf("%c\t", tab[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char tabela[LINHAS][COLUNAS];
    
    fillTable(tabela);
    
    printTable(tabela);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays.  Often, the name of an array is treated like a pointer, but you can't just treat an object of type `char[3][3]` as if it were a `char *`, because it's not.  In your code, in the call `fillTable(linhas, colunas, tabela);`, `tabela` decays to a pointer to an object of type `char[3]`, not to a pointer to an object of type `char`.   You could hard code the 3 and declare `int fillTAble(int, int, char (*)[3])`, but that would not be very flexible, but I think you are trying to do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int fillTable(int, int, void *);
int printTable(int, int, void *);

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int linhas = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0) : 3;
        int colunas = argc > 2 ? strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0) : 3;

        if( linhas > 1024 || colunas > 1024 || linhas < 1 || colunas < 1 ){
                fprintf(stderr, "Dimensions must be in [1,1024]\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        char tabela[linhas][colunas];

        fillTable(linhas, colunas, tabela);
        printTable(linhas, colunas, tabela);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int
fillTable(int linhas, int colunas, void *v)
{
        char (*tabela)[colunas] = v;
        for( int x = 0; x < linhas; x++ ){
                for( int y = 0; y < colunas; y++ ){
                        tabela[x][y] = 'a' + ( x + y )  % ( 'z' - 'a' );
                }
        }
        return 0;
}

int
printTable(int linhas, int colunas, void *v)
{
        char (*tab)[colunas] = v;
        for( int x = 0; x < linhas; x++ ){
                for( int y = 0; y < colunas; y++ ){
                        printf("%c\t",tab[x][y]);
                }
                putchar('\n');
        }
        return 0;
}
```

It is common the treat a `char *` as if it were a multi-dimensional array by computing your own row and column offsets, but you cannot just pretend that a multi-dimensional array of `char` is a `char *`.  It's not. If you want to treat a `char *` like a multi-dimensional array, you might do it like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void fillTable(int, int, char *);
void printTable(int, int, char *);

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int linhas = argc > 1 ? strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0) : 3;
        int colunas = argc > 2 ? strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 0) : 3;

        if( linhas < 1 || colunas < 1 ){
                fprintf(stderr, "Dimensions must be > 0\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        char *tabela = malloc(sizeof *tabela * linhas * colunas);
        if( tabela == NULL ){
                perror("malloc");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        fillTable(linhas, colunas, tabela);
        printTable(linhas, colunas, tabela);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void
fillTable(int linhas, int colunas, char *tabela)
{
        for( int x = 0; x < linhas; x++ ){
                char *row = tabela + x * colunas;
                for( int y = 0; y < colunas; y++ ){
                        row[y] = 'a' + ( x + y ) % ( 'z' - 'a' );
                }
        }
}

/* Here's a slightly more elegant technique */
void
printTable(int linhas, int colunas, char *tab)
{
        for( int x = 0; x < linhas; tab += colunas, x++ ){
                for( int y = 0; y < colunas; y++ ){
                        putchar(tab[y]);
                        putchar('\t');
                }
                putchar('\n');
        }
}
```

This has the benefit of being able to handle larger data structures and being able to gracefully handle errors.  If you try to allocate a large variable length array on the stack, you will (most likely) get a segfault, but if `malloc` fails you can abort gracefully.